# Redirect to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am developing an iOS app for iPhone and iPad. I have two storyboard files, called: Main_iPhone and Main_iPad. I have made a loginscreen in these storyboards and I have set up a LoginViewController. After a succesfull login, I want to redirect the user to another screen in Main_iPhone or Main_iPad. I gave this screen the name Dashboard and in the Identity Inspector the custom class DashboardViewController. I have created this file.

I'm developing for iOS 7 in Xcode 5

How can I redirect the user to my dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a few way you can do it.
First is create DashboardViewController and present it to view hierarchy:

```
DashboardViewController *vc = [[DashboardViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Another one is create segue in storyboard from Login to Dashboard and when you want to redirect just call:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGUE_IDENTIFIRE" sender:nil];
```

SEGUE_IDENTIFIRE is a segue name you need to set up in storyboard.

Comment: I get the following error when I trying the first way: Attempt to present <DashboardViewController: 0x1553b100> on <LoginViewController: 0x1557cda0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: How do you present LoginViewController? Can you show the code?

Comment: Because I do not yet have an API available to log in, I have made some custom code to login in the ViewDidLoad method in LoginViewController. Just if(1 == 1). In this statement I want to redirect to the dashboard.

Comment: It's shouldn't be any issue, what I'm asking is how do you present the login to view hierarchy, is it your root view controller, is it embedded in Navigation controller, etc?

Comment: It is a single View Controller I guess. (I don't really understand what you means. But after I created my storyboard file, I dragged a View Controller in the Storyboard) Hopefully it's clear enough ;)

Comment: Where do you call this line: [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];, in which method? Is it viewDidLoad? if so try move it to viewDidAppeare.

Comment: I moved it to viewDidAppeare. I get a black screen in my app now.

Comment: Have you got any error? Try add this before you call [self presentViewController...   [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Comment: I believe you have some issue in LoginViewController or you add LoginViewController wrongly to the view hierarchy.

Comment: I will try still something else. Anyway thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose, when you complete the login you can switch through storyboards by instantiating a UIStoryboard object and presenting new UIViewController that must be instantiated with method of UIStoryboad object, below an example:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                            @"myOtherStoryboard" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
                                  @"myViewOfOtherStoryaboard"] animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, users end up reaching this if they only search for "redirect to another view controller". So here is a solution that I would be looking for...

**Swift 3** solution

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerID")
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```