# Redirect segue from one view controller to a different one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I can't find an answer to this seemingly basic question. Let's say I have a storyboard with two view controllers A and B and a segue transition from one to another. Now, I created a different view controller C and now would like to redirect the existing segue from A to C.

I Ctrl dragged it, command dragged it, etc. it does not seem to work. In the real app, I have way too many segues to try to re-create them from scratch. Is there an easier way?

This question is not a duplicate as flagged since I'm trying to reuse existing segue, not direct to a different controller.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect to another view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632784/redirect-to-another-view-controller)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1,using XML file**

- First,right click the Storyboard file.Then select open as Source
     Code

[image]

- Search segue,then change the **destination id**

  ```
    <segue destination="Esd-4c-JQq" kind="show" id="Jnu-RW-1O5"/>
  ```

**Option 2,using Interface Builder**

- First, selected the segue source ViewController

[image]

- Second,Create a same segue(Control+drag),like picture shows

[image]

- Now,you have two same segue,

[image]

You just need to delete the old one

Comment: Is there way also to change source of segue? For example I created by mistake segue from whole view controller to another instead of TableViewCell as a source. Can I change its source from main view to TableViewCell without deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

You can drag segue from ViewController icon at the top of ViewController to other Controllers.

Just give identifier to segue by clicking segue pointer on storyboard and then opening attribute inspector and finally you have to do just that code.

Case 1: Push Segue to B from A

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushB" sender:self]; //PushB is segue identifier
```

Case 2: Push Segue to C from A

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushC" sender:self];
```

Note : You must have Navigation Controller as initial point of storyboard before performing `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the previous one from A to B and then recreate new one from A to C.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to avoid. I have way too many existing segues connected back and forth.